# Bundle install error : ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I try to install ruby bundler with `bundler install` have some errors this what the command output

```
marox@marox-desktop:~/fzafaz$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.7.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Using rack 1.6.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Using globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.1
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using debugger-ruby_core_source 1.3.8
with native extensions 
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150605-30249-fvdh3c.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./221/ruby_debug.h (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in `open'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in `copy_file'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:485:in `copy_file'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:402:in `block in cp'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1570:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1584:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1568:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    from /home/marox/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:401:in `cp'
    from extconf.rb:83:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `each'
    from extconf.rb:82:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/marox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/marox/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386762/4787082) say by installing gcc but still not working .

As I can understand that the problem start from `Using debugger-ruby_core_source 1.3.8`

Answer (score 4):

debugger gem doesn't work with ruby 2, try [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)

Comment: How to replace the current debugger with this and install bundler using it please ?

Comment: replace:

`gem 'debugger'`

with `gem 'byebug'` in your Gemfile, then rerun the bundle command

Comment: Sorry but I really didn't understand please explain further, and so sorry .

Comment: @Abddoo, you should read [bundler](http://bundler.io/#getting-started) and [rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) getting started guides.  An explanation of working with your Gemfile/gems is included in both of them and to make a working app you should read those at the very least.  Once you understand using the Gemfile/bundler, swapping byebug in place of debugger should be simple for you.